# leaflet with R: add text labels

Tags: r, leaflet, geospatial, data-visualization, spatial

This code is taken from [this page](http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html):

```
library(leaflet)
leaflet(data = quakes[1:20,]) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat, popup = ~as.character(mag))
```

Instead of markers, is there any way to plot `mag` as text labels?

Answer (score 29):

**UPDATE**

When this answer was posted, I think `addLabelOnlyMarkers()` was not officially included in the CRAN version. As of the 8th of January, 2018, leaflet is in version 1.1.0 on CRAN. This version has the function. No need to download a github version.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

If you have your `leaflet` package installed from GitHub, you can do

```
leaflet(data = quakes[1:20,]) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addLabelOnlyMarkers(~long, ~lat, label =  ~as.character(mag), 
                      labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T, direction = 'top', textOnly = T))
```

[image]

---

The `addPopups` function might be a valuable workaround if you don't want to work with the package version from GitHub. (This was the case before the official release of `addLabelOnlyMarkers()` in the CRAN version.)

```
leaflet(data = quakes[1:20,]) %>% addTiles() %>%
        addPopups(~long, ~lat, ~as.character(mag), 
        options = popupOptions(minWidth = 20, closeOnClick = FALSE, closeButton = FALSE))
```

Comment: Do you know if there is by now a new solution for 'non-Github' users? Your `addPopups` solution is working, but it is not very graphical attractive.

Answer (score 5):

You can add static/hover labels to markers

https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/blob/master/inst/examples/labels.R

Demo 
http://rpubs.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet-awesome-markers
http://rpubs.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet-label

Comment: Hi, i tried to make your example but all the `label` options doesent work for me. Any idea ? `unused argument (label = htmltools::HTML("<em>I'm a HTML Label</em>"))`

Comment: @ChristopheD. You need to build the Leaflet package from the Master Branch, the changes are not yet pushed to CRAN.

Comment: Ok ! Thanks @Bhaskar Karambelkar.

Comment: I have constructed from the Master and still get that error. It is confounding.

Comment: Works well. But needs to be installed from GitHub, not from CRAN. Find out how to install it from GitHub here: https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet

Comment: @elevendollar this should be a part of the answer. Why is "label" missing from the main package I wonder? I installed leaflet so long ago, I forgot that I installed from github.